# mysql group by, sum groups, then get rank compared to other group sums

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a mysql database (phpmyadmin) and php on my website. The problem I am having is I have a database where users register and can accrue points. Every user is also placed into a location on a map (zone).

I want to be able to:

1. Group the users into their zones then
2. SUM all points for the zone then
3. Find the zones rank compared to the other zones then
4. Finally get their rank as a percentage out of 71 possible zones

I would like to ouput their percentage out of 71 in php and do this for every zone.

Here is the code I have gotten to work so far. This pulls the data from the database and displays it as two columns with the zone on the left and the sum of all points in that zone on the right. I am not sure where to go from here or if outputting this data will help achieving my overall goal. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
<?php
require ('connect_db.php');

$sql = "SELECT zone, SUM(total) FROM UserInfo GROUP BY zone ORDER BY SUM(total) DESC LIMIT 10"; 

        $result = $dbc->query($sql);

echo "<table>"; 


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['zone'] . "</td><td>" . $row['SUM(total)'] . "</td>  </tr>";  
}

echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close(); 

   ?>
```

And here is the output for the query:

```
zone  sum_of_zone

zone1   119860
zone24  67200
zone2   66400
zone70  18990
zone12  18760
zone57  18400
zone4   17400
zone13  14400
zone65  11200
zone70  10400
```

Comment: Can you pls elaborate on the percentage point?

Comment: So for zone1 it would be rank 1/71 or .01 percent and get the percentage for that as a whole number. So zone70 would be 10/71 or .14 percent